# Output changed when release the button in python

Tags: python, arduino

I'm developing an algorithm that the signal will send to the Firebase by using python. The flow is when I pressing the button it will detected and count as 1 times when it release.

The python code i try is like this

```
AS = serial.Serial('COM8',9600)
url = 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com/'
AoS = 40
FB = firebase.FirebaseApplication(url, None)

result = FB.patch('/ParkingSeat/',{'Amount of the seats': str(AoS) + '/40'})
while (1==1):
    if(AS.inWaiting()>0):
        msg = AS.readline().strip().decode()
        if (msg == '1'):
            print ("Waiting for release")
            print (msg)
            if (AoS>0) and (msg == '0'):
                AoS-=1
                print ("The Signal now is " + str(AoS))
                result = FB.patch('/ParkingSeat/',{'Amount of the seats': str(AoS) + '/40'})
        if (msg == '2'):
            print ("Waiting for release")
            print (msg)
            if (AoS<40) and (msg == '0'):
                AoS+=1
                print ("The Signal now is " + str(AoS))
                result = FB.patch('/ParkingSeat/',{'Amount of the seats': str(AoS) + '/40'})
        print(msg)
```

and the arduino code i try is like this

```
const int BUTTON1 = 6;
const int BUTTON2 = 7;
String i, j, x;

int ButtonState = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(BUTTON2, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON1) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    i = "1";
    Serial.println(i);
  } 
  else if (digitalRead(BUTTON2) == LOW) {
    delay(500);
    j = "2";
    Serial.println(j);
  } 
  else {
    delay(500);
    x = "0";
    Serial.println(x);
  }
}
```

I'm connecting python with the arduino also. And the arduino is keep sending the signal to python as 0. When press button1 or button2, it will send 1 or 2.

So, the code i'm trying is user pressing the button1 or button2 is giving an output as 1 1 1 1 1 and the result will send after user release the button at once.

But now my code only can do receive the signal while pressing button1 or button2. When i keep pressing the button, it will keep sending the signal but i don't want. How can i write like signal will send after release the button at once?

Comment: What is the question then?

Comment: @M.R. Sorry I modified the question again

Comment: Please add your Arduino code too.

Comment: @M.R. Okay. The code added. Thanks for helping!